# Add-Migrations: Value does not fall within expected range

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image]

This happens in the package manager console. What does the red text mean?
After I run the command, the migration file is generated, but it's empty.

I can't find an answer anywhere else. I'm very frustrated. I've done a research in google but that error happens in many situations different than this one.

Comment: Do I see EF 6.2.0-beta1 there?

Comment: I'll try updating EF and reach you back with the results

Comment: Why are you using EF 6.2 beta1?

Comment: I don't know, I just installed it without thinking. I'm correcting that now.

Comment: @GertArnold There is an expression in English called "Bulls Eye" or something, in Spanish it's "Justo en el clavo". You were right, you pointed the cause of the error with 100% accuracy. I love StackOverflow!

Comment: I'll try to edit the question with the solution so others might learn from my problem in the future.

Comment: Maybe it's something to [report to the EF team](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues). After all, you promoted yourself to a beta tester now :)

Comment: Answers do in the Answer section, not the question (I have rolled back your edit). Add your own answer and accept it to close this out.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sounds reasonable

Comment: @GertArnold [I've just reported the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/366). I hope it helps them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to "downgrade" Entity Framework to 6.1.3. I guess the cause was a bug with the beta version. I was using: 6.2.0 beta.

Thank you guys for pointing this out! Thank you [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold). You rock!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbtMp.png)

in my case the problem was silly; select the proper project inside the Package manager console

Comment: this could have been a comment and need not be an answer.